Detect change of SimpleChanges in ngOnChanges if Input with observable
In Angular, I usually use ngOnChanges to detect what was change from parent component.
But now, I got confuse when declare as following:
  @Input() data: Observable<Student>;


And in ngOnChanges method:
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.data?.currentValue) {
      // code here
    }
  }

In this code, I want to pass data (data get from API) from Parent to Child. In Child, I'll subscribe the data to bind to layout.
What I want here, when there is any change in Parent, the Child should listen and re-bind with new data to layout.
But with data is observable type, the code 'changes.data?.currentValue' can know when it changes?
Please advise

ngOnChanges will be called whenever Input values from the parent component change. In order to trigger a change when the Observable emits a new value, you’ll need to subscribe to the observable from the parent component and pass the emitted value to the child.
This can be done as follows:
Parent Component Template
<child-component [data]=“(studentObservable$ | async)”></child-component>

Child Component
@Input() data: Student;


thanks for your help, I applied as your suggestion and now it can work correctly.
